# HSV to RGB (and back) without floating point math in Python

Tags: python, rgb, hsv

Anyone know of a good python algorithm for converting HSV color to RGB (and vice versa) that doesn't depend on any external modules? I'm working on some animation generation code and want to support the HSV colorspace, but it's running on a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to avoid any floating point.

Comment: So when you say, external module, does that mean: https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html (a standard library) is not an option?

Comment: Well... I'm fine with a built in module like that but only if it doesn't use float, which colorsys does. It uses 0.0 to 1.0 for everything but I need 0 to 255

Comment: can't really debate language choice... no option here. It has to be possible.

Comment: Have you tried using `colorsys`? Is it too slow?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using now, but it requires float.

Comment: If the values are between 0 and 1, instead of 0 and 255, then just multiply them by 255...?

Comment: but then I'm still doing a float mutliply... I realize it's probably not that bad, but trying to avoid ALL float

Comment: Can you just use http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html with the obvious modifications from float to int? Won't be reversible transformation, but it should work.

Answer (score 5):

This site [here](https://literateprograms.org/rgb_to_hsv_color_space_conversion__c_.html) takes you through the steps, including how to do it using integer division. Here is a python port of the RGB to HSV function described in there

```
def RGB_2_HSV(RGB):
    ''' Converts an integer RGB tuple (value range from 0 to 255) to an HSV tuple '''

    # Unpack the tuple for readability
    R, G, B = RGB

    # Compute the H value by finding the maximum of the RGB values
    RGB_Max = max(RGB)
    RGB_Min = min(RGB)

    # Compute the value
    V = RGB_Max;
    if V == 0:
        H = S = 0
        return (H,S,V)


    # Compute the saturation value
    S = 255 * (RGB_Max - RGB_Min) // V

    if S == 0:
        H = 0
        return (H, S, V)

    # Compute the Hue
    if RGB_Max == R:
        H = 0 + 43*(G - B)//(RGB_Max - RGB_Min)
    elif RGB_Max == G:
        H = 85 + 43*(B - R)//(RGB_Max - RGB_Min)
    else: # RGB_MAX == B
        H = 171 + 43*(R - G)//(RGB_Max - RGB_Min)

    return (H, S, V)
```

Which gives correct results when compared to the colorsys functions

```
import colorsys
RGB = (127, 127, 127)

Converted_2_HSV = RGB_2_HSV(RGB)
Verify_RGB_2_HSV = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(RGB[0], RGB[1], RGB[2])

print Converted_2_HSV
>>> (0, 0, 127)

print Verify_RGB_2_HSV # multiplied by 255 to bring it into the same scale
>>> (0.0, 0.0, 127.5)
```

And you can check that the output is still in fact an integer

```
type(Converted_2_HSV[0])
>>> <type 'int'>
```

Now for the reverse function. The original source can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/storborg/Public/hsvtorgb.c), and here is the Python port.

```
def HSV_2_RGB(HSV):
    ''' Converts an integer HSV tuple (value range from 0 to 255) to an RGB tuple '''

    # Unpack the HSV tuple for readability
    H, S, V = HSV

    # Check if the color is Grayscale
    if S == 0:
        R = V
        G = V
        B = V
        return (R, G, B)

    # Make hue 0-5
    region = H // 43;

    # Find remainder part, make it from 0-255
    remainder = (H - (region * 43)) * 6; 

    # Calculate temp vars, doing integer multiplication
    P = (V * (255 - S)) >> 8;
    Q = (V * (255 - ((S * remainder) >> 8))) >> 8;
    T = (V * (255 - ((S * (255 - remainder)) >> 8))) >> 8;


    # Assign temp vars based on color cone region
    if region == 0:
        R = V
        G = T
        B = P
    
    elif region == 1:
        R = Q; 
        G = V; 
        B = P;

    elif region == 2:
        R = P; 
        G = V; 
        B = T;

    elif region == 3:
        R = P; 
        G = Q; 
        B = V;

    elif region == 4:
        R = T; 
        G = P; 
        B = V;

    else: 
        R = V; 
        G = P; 
        B = Q;


    return (R, G, B)
```

And we can verify the result in the same way as before

```
interger_HSV = (127, 127, 127)
Converted_2_RGB = HSV_2_RGB(interger_HSV)
Verify_HSV_2_RGB = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

print Converted_2_RGB
>>> (63, 127, 124)

print type(Converted_2_RGB[0])
>>> <type 'int'>

print Verify_HSV_2_RGB # multiplied these by 255 so they are on the same scale
>>> (63.75, 127.5, 127.5)
```

The integer arithmetic does introduce some errors, however depending on the application these might be ok.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `S = 255 * ((RGB_Max - RGB_Min) / V)` will either be wrong most of the time (in Python 2), or uses float division (in Python 3). In Python 2 where `/` does integer division, it gets saturations of 255 and 0 correct, but nothing in between. Try getting rid of the outermost parentheses and I think it will work. Also, you probably should also be using the `//` operator everywhere you want integer division, for forwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've updated the answer to include your suggestions and changed the test cases to not be right on the boundaries.

Comment: I must ask, in the HSV to RGB function, is there a particular reason the remainder is found with `(H - (region * 43)) * 6` and not simply `(H % 43) * 6`?

Comment: Just FYI, I was able to translate the HSV to RGB into micropython with the `@micropython.viper` code emitter trivially. The existing code would execute in about 100us on an ESP32. When I changed it to the `@micropython.native` code emitter, it went down to 50us. With viper, it was about 25us. When I changed it to pass two byte buffers to store the inputs and outputs and ran the loop inside the viper function, I got it down to 5us per HSV tuple, which is plenty to drive many LEDs at high framerates!

Comment: link rot: correct link is: https://literateprograms.org/rgb_to_hsv_color_space_conversion__c_.html